# Is it recommended to upgrade a deployed v2 azure function to v3 or is it better to create new resources and deploy to them from scratch?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have a function deployed to azure running the v2 runtime.  If I go to the function in the portal to try to upgrade it to v3, I see this message "Cannot upgrade with existing functions: Major version upgrades can introduce breaking changes to languages and bindings. When upgrading major versions of the runtime, consider creating a new function app and migrate your functions to this new app."

However, I was able to change the function in Visual Studio and deploy, using a simple test deploy of right-click publish, and the publishing process upgraded the deployed function to runtime v3.

Are there any gotchas we may run into using this approach?  Is it better practice to create new azure function resources to deploy to a clean v3 azure function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently no one else has this question or the answer is obvious.  In any case, here's Microsoft's recommendation from their support personnel (grammar/language translation is Microsoft's):

*Based on the official documentation changing the version can be made by changing the App Setting "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION" value form ~2 to ~3 however this can cause some problems if there are any dependencies unique to version 2 of the runtime, you can read more about this in the following link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#migrating-from-2x-to-3x*

*Now based on my experience the safest an easiest way to archive [achieve] this is to deploy the code into a Function app that was created targeting the version 3 of the runtime this is to assure [ensure] that it will only have the dependencies form [from] version 3 and not having anything extra from 2 left after changing the version directly from the portal
The idea with this is to avoid having conflicts from between assets form version 2 or missing assets from version 3*

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using c# function, if yes, the major update about v2 to v3 is the .net core version. So mostly if your code could work with the update that means your dependencies are compatible with .net core3, so mostly it won't crash.

And there is an official doc about [migrating from 2.x to 3.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#migrating-from-2x-to-3x).

And about deploying, if the runtime is different when you deploy it will prompt to update the portal runtime, so it won't affect the function running.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, my question is really around the deployed version.  I'm able to migrate to v3 locally without a problem.  Just want to know if there will be issues with the actual deployed version in the portal upgrading things there?  Or if it is better to start with a new, clean portal container for the function.